# Render texture in 3d space with XNA

Tags: xna

I have made an augmented reality app in XNA that displays a 3d model over an SLAR marker (Silverlight Augmented Reality-toolkit).
I would like to display an rectangle floating over the 3d model showing a texture, but I'm not sure what object to use.
Texture2D doesn't have any 3d space rendering capabilties I know of, is there anything else I can use?
The texture I would like to show is generated using the SetData method so it needs to be a Texture2D or an object with simular SetData method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to render  [Textured Quad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464051%28v=XNAGameStudio.40%29.aspx).

This basically means you're drawing a rectangle in 3d space, and texturing it with whatever texture you'd like.

The link i supplied covers the basics of doing this.

- Notice that the link involved XNA 4.0 (not sure if there are any changes from previous releases), but the sample also exists for earlier versions of XNA.